# Making sure maven is running from scratch with a clean repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am pretty new to Maven and really not trying to fully learn it right now, just trying to install my java project. 
I get some errors (it is from a Hadoop Crunch project) but the errors feel like they are referring to my older code that was doing a division and could be div by zero.

So anyway: Currrently I am dong `mvn clean install` but looks like there is something its cache still? is there a more powerful way of doing this such that I make sure nothing is coming from its cache, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for your repo at `C:\Users\youruser\.m2` or `~/.m2`, you can delete that whenever you want but it will cause a "Download the Internet" the next time you do something.
That's obviously not the solution for daily use, the `mvn clean install` does compile and put the binaries of your project in your local repository from scratch, but if you have SNAPSHOT dependencies to separate projects (I'm not talking about submodules, I mean projects in some other directory) then you would need to go to those projects first and do `mvn clean install` there first so that your local repository has the latest binaries.

Comment: so I can delete the WHOLE .M2 Folder you mean?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark yes but that's an extreme measure because you will have to download a bunch of things again, you can check inside the dir structure and delete only your packages as an alternative. In any case that's not the recommended solution, you shouldn't need to do any of this unless you are experiencing a strange maven situation/bug .